# Бесконечная перезагрузка QEMU, при попытке входа в защищённый режим

Tags: ассемблер, ос

Здравствуйте! Имеется следующий Assembler-код загружаемый в память по адресу 0x7E00:

```
use16
global start1
extern kernel_start

start1:
  jmp 0x0000:entry
entry:
  mov ax, cs
  mov ds, ax

;очистить экран
  mov ax, 0x0003
  int 0x10

;открыть A20
  in  al, 0x92
  or  al, 2
  out 0x92, al

;Загрузить адрес и размер GDT в GDTR
  lgdt  [gdtr]
;Запретить прерывания
  cli
;Запретить немаскируемые прерывания
  in  al, 0x70
  or  al, 0x80
  out 0x70, al

;Переключиться в защищенный режим
  mov  eax, cr0
  or   al, 1
  mov  cr0, eax

;Загрузить в CS:EIP точку входа в защищенный режим
  O32 jmp 00001000b:pm_entry

;32-битная адресация
use32
;Точка входа в защищенный режим
pm_entry:
;Загрузить сегментные регистры (кроме SS)
  mov  ax, cs
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax

  mov  edi, 0xB8000             ;начало видеопамяти в видеорежиме 0x3
  mov  esi, msg                 ;выводимое сообщение
  cld
loop:                           ;цикл вывода сообщения
 lodsb                         ;считываем очередной символ строки
  test al, al                   ;если встретили 0
  jz   exit                    ;прекращаем вывод
  stosb                         ;иначе выводим очередной символ
  mov  al, 7                    ;и его атрибут в видеопамять
  stosb
  jmp  loop
exit:

  jmp  $                        ;зависаем

msg:
  db  'Hello World!', 0

;Глобальная таблица дескрипторов.
gdt:
  db  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,      0x00,      0x00, 0x00 
  db  0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 10011010b, 11001111b, 0x00
gdt_size  equ $ - gdt

;данные, загружаемые в регистр GDTR
gdtr:
  dw  gdt_size - 1
  dd  gdt
```

Он практически полностью скопирован из данной статьи: https://habrahabr.ru/post/104988/. Насколько я понимаю он должен создать сегмент кода лимитом 0xFFFF + 1010b и базой на 0x00, затем вывести "Hello world!" напрямую в видеопамять. Но в итоге после компиляции и запуска данного кода QEMU бесконечно перезагружается - выводит [image: QEMU бесконечно перезагружается]

иногда ещё успевает вывестись "Booting from floppy..." и экран очищается, затем снова всё это выводится и очищается и так бесконечно. Мне кажется, проблема в том, что автор статьи располагает этот код в 1-ном загрузчике по адресу 0x7C00, а я во 2-ном, по адресу 0x7E00. Но я не уверен. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

**UPD**

```
00000000 <start1>:
   0:   ea                      .byte 0xea
   1:   05                      .byte 0x5
   2:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
    ...

00000005 <entry>:
   5:   b8 03 00 cd 10          mov    eax,0x10cd0003
   a:   e4 92                   in     al,0x92
   c:   0c 02                   or     al,0x2
   e:   e6 92                   out    0x92,al
  10:   0f 01 16                lgdtd  [esi]
  13:   73 00                   jae    15 <entry+0x10>
  15:   fa                      cli    
  16:   e4 70                   in     al,0x70
  18:   0c 80                   or     al,0x80
  1a:   e6 70                   out    0x70,al
  1c:   0f 20 c0                mov    eax,cr0
  1f:   0c 01                   or     al,0x1
  21:   0f 22 c0                mov    cr0,eax
  24:   66 ea 2a 00 00 7e       jmp    0x7e00:0x2a

0000002a <pm_entry>:
  2a:   66 b8 08 00             mov    ax,0x8
  2e:   8e c8                   mov    cs,eax
  30:   66 b8 10 00             mov    ax,0x10
  34:   8e d8                   mov    ds,eax
  36:   bf 00 80 0b 00          mov    edi,0xb8000
  3b:   be 4e 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x4e
  40:   fc                      cld    

00000041 <loop>:
  41:   ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
  42:   84 c0                   test   al,al
  44:   74 06                   je     4c <exit>
  46:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
  47:   b0 07                   mov    al,0x7
  49:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
  4a:   eb f5                   jmp    41 <loop>

0000004c <exit>:
  4c:   eb fe                   jmp    4c <exit>

0000004e <msg>:
  4e:   48                      dec    eax
  4f:   65 6c                   gs ins BYTE PTR es:[edi],dx
  51:   6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[edi],dx
  52:   6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]
  53:   20 57 6f                and    BYTE PTR [edi+0x6f],dl
  56:   72 6c                   jb     c4 <kernel_start+0x4b>
  58:   64 21 00                and    DWORD PTR fs:[eax],eax

0000005b <gdt>:
    ...
  63:   ff                      (bad)  
  64:   ff 00                   inc    DWORD PTR [eax]
  66:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
  68:   9a cf 00 ff ff 00 00    call   0x0:0xffff00cf
  6f:   00                      .byte 0x0
  70:   92                      xchg   edx,eax
  71:   cf                      iret   
    ...

00000073 <gdtr>:
  73:   17                      pop    ss
  74:   00 5b 00                add    BYTE PTR [ebx+0x0],bl
    ...

00000079 <kernel_start>:
  79:   66 55                   push   bp
  7b:   66 89 e5                mov    bp,sp
  7e:   66 83 ec 10             sub    sp,0x10
  82:   67 66 c7 45 fc 00 80    mov    WORD PTR [di-0x4],0x8000
  89:   0b 00                   or     eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
  8b:   67 66 c7 45 f8 00 00    mov    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0x0
  92:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
  94:   eb 2d                   jmp    c3 <kernel_start+0x4a>
  96:   67 66 8b 55 f8          mov    dx,WORD PTR [di-0x8]
  9b:   67 66 8b 45 fc          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x4]
  a0:   66 01 d0                add    ax,dx
  a3:   67 c6 00 21             mov    BYTE PTR [bx+si],0x21
  a7:   67 66 8b 45 f8          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x8]
  ac:   67 66 8d 50 01          lea    dx,[bx+si+0x1]
  b1:   67 66 8b 45 fc          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x4]
  b6:   66 01 d0                add    ax,dx
  b9:   67 c6 00 0f             mov    BYTE PTR [bx+si],0xf
  bd:   67 66 83 45 f8 02       add    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0x2
  c3:   67 66 81 7d f8 9f 0f    cmp    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0xf9f
  ca:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
  cc:   7e c8                   jle    96 <kernel_start+0x1d>
  ce:   90                      nop
  cf:   66 c9                   leavew 
  d1:   66 c3                   retw
```

Comment: Не могу понять как код данных авторов может работать. В GDT определен единственный дескриптор и тип сегмента 101 - это сегмент кода с доступом на чтение и выполнение. писать в такой сегмент нельзя. А вывод на экран почему то пытаются сделать через тот же сегмент. Это должно привести к нарушению общей защиты. Необходимо как минимум определить еще и сегмент данных, который в принципе можно так же сделать на все адресное пространство и грузить в DS, ES селектор этого сегмента  ...

Comment: А вообще при попытках перехода в защищенный режим программу стоит отлаживать на слух, только убедитесь перед этим в реальном режиме, что можете воспроизводить звук через спикер и что его реально слышно. После чего в ключевых точках расставляете выбор разных частот и по слышимым нотам определяете в каком месте зависли. Это единственно доступный способ передать информацию до того момента как отладили работу с GDT и новыми селекторами

Comment: И зачем кстати все это проделывать в загрузчике. Отладьте переход в PM обычной программой запускаемой из dos. когда заработает переносите в загрузчик

Comment: @Mike я попробовал добавить дескриптор сегмента данных и загрузить ds селектором этого дескриптора - реакции нет. Добавил дамп.

Comment: А почему интересно джамп такой странный вышел `jmp    0x7e00:0x2a` он же должен был загрузить в cs 8, т.е. он должен был быть примерно `8:7e02a`.

Comment: @Mike это все моя тупость. Я почему-то решил что там нужно указать адрес кода в памяти, а не селектор. Видимо я ещё не полностью отошел от реального режима.

Comment: @Mike дебаг показал, что проблема где-то в месте jmp 8:pm_entry

Comment: или это ваш дизассемблер так странно показал, префикс 66 неверно декодировал. там по хорошему же должны были идти 2 байта сегмента и 4 байта адреса. зато позже он написал mov ax,8 / mov cs,ax  что вообще странно cs же mov не грузится

Comment: я на самом деле не к курсе как должны кодироваться адреса в командах при применении префикса 66 (смены битности инструкции)

Comment: @Mike я заменил загрузку сегментых регистров следующим кодом: https://pastebin.com/d8rDxV2Q

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58152/discussion-between-wcobalt-and-mike).

Comment: @Mike не получил уведомление о Вашем сообщении, поэтому отвечаю спустя 11 дней. Загляните в чат.

Comment: @Mike Вы говорили про то чтобы запустить elf-файл нужно написать загрузчик elf. А каким образом можно писать OC на C не используя elf?

Comment: Во первых gcc позволяет компилировать bin файлы. Во вторых при разработке ОС в том числе и решаются вопросы для создания линкера в собственный формат выполнимых файлов и пишутся соответствующие модули к gcc.

Comment: @Mike понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Mike просто проблема в том чтобы вызвать C-функцию из ассемблера. С бинарными файлами это, походу, невозможно.

Comment: значит делайте elf и грузите его с помощью grub. https://habrahabr.ru/company/neobit/blog/173263/

Answer (score 2):

Бесконечная перезагрузка при попытках перехода в защищенный режим возникает из за тройной ошибки ([Tripple fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_fault)). Которая возникает на данном этапе из за любой ошибки в коде. Будь то неверная инструкция или недоступный адрес памяти. При ошибке процессор пытается вызвать обработчик исключения, но таблица прерываний защищенного режима еще не определена, тогда процессор пытается вызвать обработчик исключения "двойная ошибка" (int 8), но так же не может этого сделать, после чего пытается отключится, на что материнские платы и эмуляторы запускают перезагрузку.

В том источнике, откуда вы взяли пример кода, допущена грубейшая ошибка (не всему в интернете можно верить, всегда обращайтесь к первоисточникам, документации на процессор). Запись в видеопамять пытаются производить используя для этого селектор сегмента кода. В защищенном режиме запись в сегменты кода невозможна и приводит к исключению общей защиты. Вам необходимо создать в GDT еще один дескриптор, так же описывающий всю память, но с типом (биты 41-43) "001" - сегмент данных, доступный для чтения и записи и использовать для доступа к тексту сообщения и видеопамяти селектор этого дескриптора.

Кроме этого, по итогам переписки в чате было выяснено, что подобные эксперименты в коде начальной загрузки чреваты и другими проблемами. Во первых не все ассемблеры одинаково полезны (или мы просто не умеем их готовить ?). У ТС ассемблер на инструкцию `O32 jmp 00001000b:pm_entry` генерил невозможный опкод. Использовал префикс 32-bit (66) но при этом адрес перехода кодировал двумя байтами, вместо четырех. Нормальная инструкция длинного, 32-bit джампа из 16-битного режима должна выглядеть как `66 EA 4х-байтное-смещение 2х-байтный-селектор`.

Вторая проблема оказалась в том, что загрузчик загружал код не в те адреса, которые предполагал при сборке линковщик, в итоге загружался не правильный адрес GDT и jmp переходил не туда, куда ожидалось. Поэтому при отладке начальной загрузки всегда проверяйте в какие адреса реально попал ваш код (например выведя свой текущий адрес на экран). И указывайте правильные адреса линкеру.

В качестве демонстрации рабочий код, не зависящий от адреса загрузки (сам корректирующий все адреса в зависимости от положения в памяти). Дабы можно было позволить себе несколько лишних инструкций в начале, ожидается, что загрузка произойдет в участок выровненный на 16 байт. Загрузчик по другому вряд ли загрузит. Диалект NASM.

```
; директивы ORG нет, код рассчитан на сборку линкером по 0 смещению
[BITS 16]
entry:
    call get_ip       ; Помещаем в стек адрес, следующий за текущей инструкцией
get_ip:
    mov ax, 0x0003
    int 0x10          ; очистка экрана
    xor ebx,ebx       ; надо очистить старшую часть ebx, на будущее для 32-bit режима
    pop bx            ; достаем в BX из стека адрес инструкции в начале
    and bx,0xFFF0     ; отбрасываем размер первых инструкций
                      ; далее по коду BX более ни для чего не используем,
                      ; в нем величина коррекции положения
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, [jmp_addr+bx+2]  ; достаем смещение перехода из инструкции jmp dword
                             ; 2 байта пропущено от метки т.к. там 66 EA
    add ax, bx               ; корректируем адрес
    mov [jmp_addr+bx+2], ax  ; пишем обратно в инструкцию jmp
    mov ax, [gdt_addr+bx]    ; берем адрес GDT
    add ax, bx               ; корректируем
    mov [gdt_addr+bx], ax    ; кладем обратно

    jmp flush_conv           ; т.к. мы правили собственный код, делаем короткий jmp
flush_conv:                  ; для очистки очереди команд процессора
    in  al, 0x92
    or  al, 2
    out 0x92, al             ; открываем A20

    lgdt [gdtr+bx]
    cli
    in  al, 0x70
    or  al, 0x80
    out 0x70, al             ; запрещаем NMI

    mov  eax, cr0
    or   al, 1
    mov  cr0, eax            ; защищенный режим !
jmp_addr:
    jmp dword 8:pm_entry     ; длинный переход для загрузки нового селектора в CS

[BITS 32]
pm_entry:
    mov  eax, 0x10           ; селектор сегмента данных
    mov  ds, ax              ; загружаем во все сегментные регистры
    mov  es, ax              ; что бы не оставлять значения из реального режима
    mov  fs, ax              ; по хорошему надо сделать отдельный сегмент для стека
    mov  gs, ax              ; и его селектор загрузить в ss
                             ; но мы этого не делаем, поэтому стеком пользоваться нельзя

    lea edi, [msg+ebx]       ; адрес сообщения, не забываем скорректировать
    mov esi, 0xb8000         ; линейное смещение видеопамяти
    mov ah, 7                ; цвет символов серый на черном
print:
    mov al, [ds:edi]
    test al,al
    jz  exit
    mov [ds:esi], ax
    inc esi
    inc esi
    inc edi
    jmp print
exit:
    JMP $               ; зависаем

msg db 'In protected mode !',0
  align 16              ; GDT лучше выровнять на 16 байт, для облегчения жизни процессору
gdt:
  db  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,      0x00,      0x00, 0x00 ; Zero дескриптор
  db  0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 10011010b, 11001111b, 0x00 ; Сегмент кода
  db  0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 10010010b, 11001111b, 0x00 ; Сегмент данных
gdt_size  equ $ - gdt
gdtr:                           ; переменная для загрузки GDT
  dw  gdt_size - 1
gdt_addr:                       ; точка для коррекции адреса GDT
  dd  gdt
TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0       ; дополнение до размера сектора
DW 0xAA55                       ; признак загрузочного сектора
```

Comment: к моему великому сожалению, этот код не работает. QEMU по-прежнему перезагружается. Дамп: https://pastebin.com/3PNCCyqD

Comment: @wcobalt загрузите его для начала просто, что бы он был загрузочным сектором. и просмотрите работает или нет. И еще я вам давал код печати значений. выведите на экран регистр cs. у вас в старом коде была какая то странная коррекция. возможно, у вас этот код вызывают с ненулевым cs и тогда надо будет учесть его в смещении. в принципе если он не нулевой верните jmp с которого ваш код начинался

Comment: @wcobalt А еще интересно посмотреть в дизассемблере точку которая этому участку кода управление передает из C-кода

Comment: в загрузчике всё равно не работает. При добавленном jmp 0x0000:метка тоже. Про какую это точку вы говорите?