# Защищенный режим. Когда следует разрешать прерывания?

Tags: ассемблер, ос, процессор

Требуется перейти в защищенный режим, для этого я делаю:

```
set_PE:
        mov     eax, cr0 ; прочитать регистр CR0
        or      al, 1    ; установить бит PE,
        mov     cr0, eax ; с этого момента мы в защищенном режиме
        ret

disable_interrupts:
        cli              ; запретить маскируемые прерывания
        in      al, 70h  ; индексный порт CMOS
        or      al, 80h  ; установка бита 7 в нем запрещает NMI
        out     70h, al
        ret
```

Далее мне нужно выполнить некоторые действия, в том числе программные прерывания.

Вопрос: можно ли разрешить прерывания:

```
enable_interrupts:
        in      al, 70h  ; индексный порт CMOS
        and     al, 7Fh  ; сброс бита 7 отменяет блокирование NMI
        out     70h, al
        sti              ; разрешить маскируемые прерывания
        ret
```

До выполнения кода в защищенном режиме? Или это уже не будет защищенный режим?

Просто есть пример:

```
; hello.asm
; Программа, выполняющая переход в защищенный режим и немедленный возврат.

        .model  tiny
        .code
        .386p           ; все наши примеры рассчитаны на 80386
        org     100h    ; это COM-программа
start:
        ; подготовить сегментные регистры
        push    cs
        pop     ds              ; DS - сегмент данных (и кода) нашей программы
        push    0B800h
        pop     es              ; ES - сегмент видеопамяти

        ; запретить прерывания
        call    disable_interrupts
        ; перейти в защищенный режим
        call    set_PE

        ; Мы в защишённом режиме!

        ; вывод на экран
        xor     di, di                   ; ES:DI - начало видеопамяти
        mov     si, offset message       ; DS:SI - выводимый текст
        mov     cx, message_l
        rep movsb                ; вывод текста
        mov     ax, 0720h        ; пробел с атрибутом 07h
        mov     cx, rest_scr     ; заполнить этим символом остаток экрана
        rep stosw

        ; переключиться в реальный режим
        call    clear_PE
        ; разрешить прерывания
        call    enable_interrupts

        ; подождать нажатия любой клавиши
        mov     ah, 0
        int     16h

        ; выйти из COM-программы
        ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;
;; Служебные функции
;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Запрещает маскируемые и немаскируемые прерывания
disable_interrupts:
        cli              ; запретить прерывания
        in      al, 70h  ; индексный порт CMOS
        or      al, 80h  ; установка бита 7 в нем запрещает NMI
        out     70h, al
        ret

; Разрешает маскируемые и немаскируемые прерывания
enable_interrupts:
        in      al, 70h  ; индексный порт CMOS
        and     al, 7Fh  ; сброс бита 7 отменяет блокирование NMI
        out     70h, al
        sti              ; разрешить прерывания
        ret

; Устанавливает флаг PE
set_PE:
        mov     eax, cr0 ; прочитать регистр CR0
        or      al, 1    ; установить бит PE,
        mov     cr0, eax ; с этого момента мы в защищенном режиме
        ret

; Сбрасывает флаг PE
clear_PE:
        mov     eax, cr0 ; прочитать CR0
        and     al, 0FEh ; сбросить бит PE
        mov     cr0, eax ; с этого момента мы в реальном режиме
        ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;
;; Данные
;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; текст сообщения с атрибутом после каждого символа для прямого вывода на экран
message db      'H',7,'e',7,'l',7,'l',7,'o',7,',',7,' ',7,'w',7
        db      'o',7,'r',7,'l',7,'d',7,'!',7,
; его длина в байтах
message_l = $ - message
; длина оставшейся части экрана в словах
rest_scr = (80*25) - (message_l / 2)

        end     start
```

Comment: Для начала надо разобраться с работой с памятью. До прерываний еще очень далеко. Сразу после перехода в защищенный режим все сегментные регистры должны быть перегружены и содержать не смещения сегментов в памяти, а селекторы, которые указывают на дескрипторы сегментов, расположенные в дескрипторной таблице (GDT). После этого должны быть написаны обработчики всех необходимых прерываний и сформирована дескрипторная таблица прерываний (IDT). Обработчики реального режима работать в защищенном не смогут

Comment: Разрешать прерывания до того как переписаны _все_ обработчики, которые могут быть вызваны, нельзя.

Comment: Хотя теоретически приведенный код работоспособен, за счет того, что сегментные регистры загружены еще в реальном режиме и теневая часть регистра указывает на правильные области памяти, вывод на экран вполне может произойти, но конечно называть это защищенным режимом нельзя. Так же как и разрешать прерывания, первая же попытка в прерывании перегрузить сегментный регистр приведет к исключению общей защиты, которое не будет обработано (за отсутствием обработчика), приведет к двойному нарушению и уходу процессора в перезагрузку

Comment: @Mike я использую за основу JamesM's kernel. А там asm только через asm вставки.... Есть ли где подробная инструкция по входу в защищенный режим

Comment: В интернете можно найти много статей на эту тему. Правда как показала практика в них бывают серьезные ошибки. Вот например один вопрос-ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661187/194569 там в вопросе ссылка на в принципе неплохую статью, про ошибки указано в ответе :)

Comment: Но до прерываний и тут не добираются. Это вообще отдельная тема. например вы пишите "_Далее мне нужно выполнить некоторые действия, в том числе программные прерывания_". Интересно что это за действия такие. Любые программные прерывания, вроде int 10h, 16h - это прерывания bios реального режима, они в принципе не могут работать в защищенном. Если вы хотите вызвать какое то прерывание, сначала вам надо написать обработчик этого прерывания, который выполнит сам всю работу с аппаратурой, минуя bios. А перед этим скорее всего написать несколько обработчиков исключений и аппаратных прерываний.

Comment: @Mike я пока пытаюсь сперва зайти в защищенный режим. Про обработчик пока рано думать... Проблема в том, что у меня ядро на си с asm вставками... Из-за чего инструкции на чистом asm выполнить довольно сложно + как вы и сказали - там вечно тонна ошибок

Comment: весь переход в защищенный режим лучше выполнить одной asm вставкой, без вызова каких либо функций. проблема как я понимаю может возникнуть с вот тем long jmp который должен быть верно закодирован. И жизненно необходимо настроить верно сегмент стека, потому что код на C его очень активно использует.

Comment: @Mike https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001210/jamesm-kernel-%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0

Comment: @Mike выложил в соседней теме наработки
Если сможете помочь (хотя вы и так очень помогли) - будем очень благодарны

Comment: @Mike не подскажите - какую ASM вставку следует делать?

Comment: я не знаю как на вашем диалекте в C это выразить. В любом случае я бы делал одну функцию, которая меняет бит в cr0, грузит GDT, переписывает все сегментные регистры и ... по хорошему нужен именно тот `jmp 8:.flush` что бы в регистр cs записалось 8, а не то что было в реальном режиме. если это записать не удается то можно пойти другим путем, настроить ss (и соответствующий дескриптор в gdt) так, что бы он указывал на старый стек (в принципе можно и новый сделать), переписать в стеке адрес возврата из текущей функции на длинный `8:точка-возврата` и выполнить длинный ret (far ret)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо **@Mike**

Для начала надо разобраться с работой с памятью. До прерываний еще очень далеко. Сразу после перехода в защищенный режим все сегментные регистры должны быть перегружены и содержать не смещения сегментов в памяти, а селекторы, которые указывают на дескрипторы сегментов, расположенные в дескрипторной таблице (GDT). После этого должны быть написаны обработчики всех необходимых прерываний и сформирована дескрипторная таблица прерываний (IDT). Обработчики реального режима работать в защищенном не смогут

**Разрешать прерывания до того как переписаны все обработчики, которые могут быть вызваны, нельзя.**

*Хотя теоретически приведенный код работоспособен, за счет того, что сегментные регистры загружены еще в реальном режиме и теневая часть регистра указывает на правильные области памяти, вывод на экран вполне может произойти, но конечно называть это защищенным режимом нельзя. Так же как и разрешать прерывания, первая же попытка в прерывании перегрузить сегментный регистр приведет к исключению общей защиты, которое не будет обработано (за отсутствием обработчика), приведет к двойному нарушению и уходу процессора в перезагрузку*

В интернете можно найти много статей на эту тему. Правда как показала практика в них бывают серьезные ошибки. Вот например один вопрос-ответ ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661187/194569 там в вопросе ссылка на в принципе неплохую статью, про ошибки указано в ответе :)

Но до прерываний и тут не добираются. Это вообще отдельная тема. Любые программные прерывания, вроде int 10h, 16h - это прерывания bios реального режима, они в принципе не могут работать в защищенном. Если вы хотите вызвать какое то прерывание, **сначала вам надо написать обработчик этого прерывания, который выполнит сам всю работу с аппаратурой, минуя bios**. А перед этим скорее всего написать несколько обработчиков исключений и аппаратных прерываний. –

весь переход в защищенный режим лучше выполнить одной asm вставкой, без вызова каких либо функций. проблема как я понимаю может возникнуть с вот тем **long jmp** который должен быть верно закодирован. **И жизненно необходимо настроить верно сегмент стека, потому что код на C его очень активно использует**.